# how to upload binary through application loader in XCode?

Tags: ios

I want to upload my binary to the iTunes through application loader. When I get the option to choose the app my app name is not shown there,some other app name which is also waiting for the upload in my account appears there.
How can i select my current app for upload?

Comment: I've not understand what you mean. Please explain more or attack screenshot

Comment: i have two apps in my itunes account whose status is waiting for upload.when i want to upload the binary for my second app,i go to application loader and when i get the choose option only the name of my first app appears there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this image, I guess it will answer your question. Let me know if you are facing issue.
[image]

Updated :- You need to add you app profile on iTunes for next updated version/initial version. Then will be visible to you in Application loader.Check the proper bundle Id and Version number.